# DOJO dijit.Tree widget inside dijit.form.ComboBox popup

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to put dijitTree widget inside dijit.form.ComboBox popup layout? I need to create user friendly widget for selecting an available folder in a tree. User clicks on combobox and see at dropdown popup tree with folders. After click on certain folder popup collapses and this folder appears as selected item in combobox.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to have a `Tree` inside a `ComboBox`. For your use case, what you can do is that keep the `ComboBox` disabled and when user clicks on it, then open a `Dialog` and display the `Tree` inside it. User can select the folder from the Tree. When the dialog closes, you can set the value of the ComboBox.

Comment: @Himanshu oh, that's good workaround. Didn't think of that till now. Thanks!